# One container on top of another?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have a strange one here, I have an image slideshow in one container and below it I have another container with text. In desktop view it appears as I want, however in media queries the text container seems to position itself on top of the image slideshow. Not quite sure why:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OPmxKp

Error in practice: http://gyazo.com/8c5d4622cc7f7cb25fdfb4122a5e81ba

HTML:

```
  <html>
      <head>
        <?php include('header.php'); ?>
        <?php include('footer.php'); ?>

        <title>Charlie Coplestone</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" /> 
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="footer.css" type="text/css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="header.css" type="text/css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jsbody.css" type="text/css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="headerbuttons.css" type="text/css"/>

        <script type='text/javascript' src='js/slider.js'></script>

      </head>

      <!--body-->
      <body onLoad="slideA()">
        <div id="container">
          <img src="images/slideshow/img1.jpg" id="img">
          <div id="l_holder">
            <img onClick="slide(-1)" class="left" src="images/slideshow/leftarrow.png">
          </div>
          <div id="r_holder">
            <img onClick="slide(1)" class="right" src="images/slideshow/rightarrow.png">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="container2">
          <h2>In Development - Automatic Image Slideshow in JavaScript</h2>
          <p>More work is to be done on this.</p>
        </div>
      </body>
      </html>
```

CSS:

```
        body { 
          background: #141414 url('../images/background1.png');
          background-repeat: repeat-y;
          background-attachment:fixed;
          background-position:center;
        }
        #container{
            height:450px;                                                           
            width:840px;
            margin:120px auto 0 auto;
            position:relative;
        }
        #container2{
            height:60px;
            width:840px;
            margin:0 auto;
            position:relative;
            -moz-box-shadow:0 0 5px 5px black;
            -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 5px 5px black;
            box-shadow:0 0 5px 5px black;
        }
        #container2 p{
            color:white;
            font-size:15px;
            padding-left:5px;
        }
        #container2 h2{
            color:white;
            font-size: 18px;
            text-decoration:none;
            padding-left:5px;
            padding-top:2px;
        }
        #img{
            height:450px;
            width:840px;
            position:absolute; 
            -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px black;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px black;
            box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px black;
        }
        #l_holder{
            height:450px;
            width:100px;
            position:absolute;
            left:0px;
            top:0px;  
            cursor:pointer;
        }
        #r_holder{
            height:450px;
            width:100px;
            position:absolute;
            right:0px;
            top:0px;  
            cursor:pointer;
        }
        .left{
            height:50px;
            width:50px; 
            position:absolute; 
            top:45%;
            left:0px;
        }
        .right{
            height:50px;
            width:50px; 
            position:absolute; 
            top:45%;
            right:0px;
        }
        .clear{
            clear:bottom;
        }

        @media all and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 10in){

        body { 
          background: #141414;
        }
        #container{
            width:100%;
            height:auto;
            margin-top: 3%;
        }
        #container2{
        }
        #container2 p{
        }
        #container2 h2{
        }
        #container2 .body_black_box{ 
        }
        #img{
            width:100%;
            height:auto; 
            margin-bottom: 5px;
        }
        #l_holder{
        }
        #r_holder{
        }
        .left{
        }
        .right{
        }
        .clear{
        }
        }
```

Very grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: please specify your problem...

Comment: I believe that the gif show's the problem in practice as well as my codepen.. View my codepen example and resize your browser to activate the media queries to replicate the gif's issue.

Comment: @CharlieCoplestone the GIF shoes only the issue, not the transition from the desired effect on the desktop view to the issue appearing at narrower (mobile) screen sizes. I think this was throwing people off at first (myself included).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `position: absolute` CSS set on your `#img` element is causing this issue. When you use absolute position on an inner element and the outer element is set to `height: auto`, the outer element has no idea how tall it should be because the inner element has been removed from the document flow with `position: absolute`. To maintain responsiveness, you don't want to set a strict `height: XXXpx` to the `#img` or `#container` elements in your media queries.

Solution is to remove `position: absolute` from the `#img` element's CSS

```
#img{
    height: 450px;
    width: 840px;
    /* position: absolute; */
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px black;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px black;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px black;
}
```

**[Updated codepen](http://codepen.io/jimulle/pen/qEmVOB)**

Comment: This has done the job, plus I now know something I didn't before. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the height of the container in media queries and the #img div as well to a value other than `height:auto;`

In this example i used `height:450px` since it's the one you used in your container in desktop view http://jsfiddle.net/95jkzw0b/

```
@media all and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 10in){

body { 
  background: #141414;
}
#container{
   width:100%;
    height:450px;                                 
    margin:120px auto 0 auto;
    position:relative;
}
#container2{
}
#container2 p{
}
#container2 h2{
}
#container2 .body_black_box{ 
}
#img{
    width:100%;
    height:450px; 
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
#l_holder{
}
#r_holder{
}
.left{
}
.right{
}
.clear{
}
}
```

Let me know if you still have a problem

Comment: Oh I see now, thanks for that. The only issue with the height now not being auto is that the slideshow now appears very squashed if the browser gets too narrow?

Comment: Setting the height explicitly like this removes the responsiveness.

Comment: @JRulle True, i didn't spot the position:absolute in the #img. I advice the op to go with your solution for obvious reasons. You deserve an upvote